# Acceaa Denied 403 Forbidden Error in website

Tags: cpanel

I have a file in my web host and want to download it by it's address. But I get 403 Error. the file permission is 644 .I can download a file from other place of host.

Error.

You don't have permission to access www.site.com/webservice/quran/uploads/000000000000000/backup/sp.xml on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use FileZilla for transfering files as FTP.

Comment: I want to use another purpose, I need to use my way